# ¿Como usar selectize para multiples opciones?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Tengo una duda de como utilizar el `selectize` de angular para seleccionar varias opciones, en dos diferentes selects, por ejemplo, el usuario tiene una serie de opciones para seleccionar sus gustos en cuanto a deportes y asignarle una puntuación del 1 al 10, fútbol, béisbol, baloncesto, entonces tengo lo siguiente en mi html:

```
<div class="form-group m-b-md">
  <selectize config='optionsConfig' options='sports' ng-model=""></selectize>
</div>
<input type="number" min="1" ng-model="" required>
```

Existe una opción si desea agregar otro deporte y puntuación!

y en angular

```
optionSelect:['futbol', 'baloncesto', 'tennis', 'beisbol']
```

esa información la insertaria de la siguiente manera en un array:

```
sportsPoints[
  {
    sport: 'futbol',
    points: 10
  },
  {
    sport: 'tennis',
    points: 4
  },
]
```

si me pueden ayudar lo agradecería muchísimo!

Comment: Puedo ver el codigo en Plunker, Jsbin o en lo que este escrito, no entiendo muy bien que quiere hacer, pero viendo lo que a echo, podria ayudarle. **SELECTIZE** no hace parte de AngularJS es una libreria externa. Yo puedo mostrarle una solución a lo que entendi.

Comment: seria algo como esto: http://plnkr.co/edit/oxtojjEPwkKng9iKkc14?p=preview como colocar el ng-model para que me agarre diferentes valores pero lo inserte en un mismo array y lo guarde?

Comment: Te recomiendo utilices esto, es el complemento para Angular relacionado con Selectize: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select